# Particular solution $y' = \sin x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Find the particular solution to the differential equation $y' = \sin x$ given the general solution $y = C - \cos x$ and the initial condition $y(p) = 1.$

Answer (score 1):

You are being told that $y(p) = 1:$ that is, the value we get when we plug $x=p$ into the equation $y = -\cos x + C$ is $1$.

$$y(p) = -\cos p + C = 1 \iff C = 1+\cos p$$

So the particular solution is given by $$y = -\cos x + \cos p +1$$

where $\cos p + 1$ replaces the constant $C$ as given in the general solution.

(Remember, we are treating $p$ as the $x$-value that makes $y = 1$, meaning that it is some given value $p \in \mathbb R$, we just don't happen to know what that value $p$ is.)

Answer (score 0):

You must find such a $C$, that $y(p)=C-\cos p=1$, so $C=1+\cos p$.

Comment: how do i find that c?

Comment: You know that general solution in point $p$ is $y(p)=C-\cos p$, right? Now you want to have $y(p)=1$, so it must be $C-\cos p=1$